# How to access attribute from within a separate attributes method body?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I currently have a class with a few attributes. Each of those attributes has their own methods. The structure looks as follows.

```
    class A(object):
        def __init__(self,B,C):
            self.attribute_B = B
            self.attribute_C = C

    class B():
        def foo(self):
            #Very relevant and important code
            A.attribute_C = None
            return result
```

This is a simplified version of the structure. What I would like to know is how to modify attribute_C from inside the function body of attribute_B like follows.

```
beta = B()
charlie = C()
alpha = A(beta,charlie)
print(alpha.attribute_C) # prints C
alpha.attribute_B.foo()
print(alpha.attribute_C) # prints None
```

I am aiming to modify an attribute of A within the function body of one of its attributes. I hope I have made the question clear. Any help would be appreciated! 
Thank you!

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're trying to achieve here. Is the attribute you're attempting to modify an instance?
Here `self.attribute_C = C` you set `self.attribute_C` to a class, not an instance. Then here `A.attribute_C = None` you're setting a class attribute, not an instance attribute, to `None`.

Comment: Then here `alpha.B.foo()` I'm not sure what is trying to be accomplished. `alpha` which is an instance of `A` has no `B` attribute or method so it won't do anything.

Comment: I am not sure what the correct syntax would be for the relationship between an attribute and the class it belongs to. ```self.attribute_C = C``` should be an instance of class C you are correct but in A.attribute_C = None I am not trying to set a class attribute but edit the attribute_C attribute of alpha of which B is also an attribute

Comment: Oh, ok. In that case, `self.attribute_C = C` will assign the class to `self.attribute_C`. `self.attribute_C = C()` would assign an instance of `C` to it.

Comment: You could pass an argument to the `foo` method with the instance you want to modify. So `alpha.attribute_B.foo(alpha)` and change `def foo(self):` to `def foo(self, A):`. This seems a little too abstracted for my tastes but to each it's own.

Comment: I don't understand why not change `attribute_C` directly... Instead of `alpha.attribute_B.foo()` do `alpha.attribute_C = ...` According to your example, `B` and `C` are not aware of each other (or the fact that they are part of `A` for that matter) so I don't see how that would be possible

Comment: I don't want to change it directly because I want to changed based on a conditional within foo which does not affect the return result of foo

Answer (score 1):

OOP is about encapsulation. An instance `b` of `B` should not be allowed to modifiy a parameter of an instance of `a` of `A` unless: 1. `a` is an attribute of `b` or 2. `a` is a parameter of a method of `b`. Since `b` is a parameter of `a`, it would be a really bad design to have `a` a parameter of `b`. Hence you have to pass `a` as a parameter.

Here's a working code that respects encapsulation:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, b, c):
        self.attribute_b = b
        self.attribute_c = c

class B():
    def foo(self, a):
        a.attribute_c = None
        return "result"

beta = B()
charlie = "C"
alpha = A(beta, charlie)
print(alpha.attribute_c) # prints C
alpha.attribute_b.foo(alpha)
print(alpha.attribute_c) # prints None
```

But this is really poor design. Because one day you'll see this:

```
alpha1.attribute_b.foo(alpha2)
```

And you have no way to prevent this. Here's a better code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, b, c):
        self.attribute_b = b
        self.attribute_c = c

    def foo(self):
        self.attribute_b.foo(self)

class B():
    def foo(self, a):
        a.attribute_c = None
        return "result"

beta = B()
charlie = "C"
alpha = A(beta, charlie)
print(alpha.attribute_c) # prints C
alpha.foo()
print(alpha.attribute_c) # prints None
```

*Remark:* The [State pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) uses a similar design. The `Context` has a `State` parameter. The `handle` method of the `State` takes a reference on the `Context` as parameter to be able to change the current state by calling `context.set_state(NextState())`.